# How to print Ada.Real_Time.Time variable

Tags: time, ada

How to print Ada.Real_Time.Time variable?

```
procedure Main is
    test : TValue :=
         (value => 0.7,
          timeStamp => Clock,
          status => (Valid => False, Unknown => True)
         );
begin
  -- print of Test.value
Put(Item => Test.value ,Fore => 5, Aft => 3, Exp => 0);
  -- here I want a print of timestamp

end Main;
```

I want to print timeStamp to console, how to do it? I tried to convert it to String or Integer, but with no success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important section to read is [LRM D.8](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-D-8.html), which defines `package Ada.Real_Time`.  Specifically it is worth noting [paragraph 19](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-D-8.html#p19), which says that the epoch is not specified by the language.  This means that for printing `Ada.Real_Time.Time` variables, you have to define an epoch yourself.  One such epoch could be the starting time of the application you are testing:

```ada
with Ada.Real_Time;
package Real_Time_IO is
   ...
private
   Epoch : constant Ada.Real_Time.Time := Ada.Real_Time.Clock;
end Real_Time_IO;
```

Now you can calculate time spans since the application started:

```ada
package body Real_Time_IO is
   function Since_Start return Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span is
   begin
      return Ada.Real_Time.Clock - Epoch;
   end Since_Start;
   ...
```

If we only need to use this package up to 24 hours after application start, we can be lazy and just convert the `Since_Start` result to the type `Duration`, and then to a string:

```ada
   function Since_Start return Duration is
   begin
      return Ada.Real_Time.To_Duration (Since_Start);
   end Since_Start;

   function Since_Start return String is
   begin
      return Duration'Image (Since_Start);
   end Since_Start;
```

... and I hope you know how to print strings. :-)

Comment: If you are using GNAT, `Duration’Last` is a very large number (typically > 10^20).

Comment: Yes, but you are only guaranteed 24 hours (and no leap second).

Comment: **If you are using GNAT**, you either have a 64-bit `Duration` with lsb 1 nanosecond (~ 300 years) or a 32-bit `Duration` with lsb 20 ms (~ 500 days). If not, or if there’s a chance not, you’re right, of course.

Answer (score 3):

After some research, here is a short example of how to print a Real_Time.Time

```
with Ada.Real_Time; use Ada.Real_Time;
with Ada.Calendar;
with Ada.Calendar.Formatting;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure PrintRT is
      The_Clock : Ada.Real_Time.Time := Ada.Real_Time.Clock;

      -- Convert to Time_Span   
      As_Time_Span : Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span := The_Clock - Time_Of(0, Time_Span_Zero);

      -- Epoch ?
      Epoch : constant Ada.Calendar.Time := Ada.Calendar.Time_Of(1970, 01, 01);

      Dur : Duration := Ada.Real_Time.To_Duration(As_Time_Span);
begin
      Put_Line(Ada.Calendar.Formatting.Image(Ada.Calendar."+"(Epoch, Dur)));
end PrintRT;
```

The only way to get a *Time_Span* is to use the "-" operator between two times.

As *Seconds_Count* represents the number of seconds from the Epoch, you can build a Time from it using *Time_Of*.

Then converting it to duration allows you to find the correct date.

Comment: it looks like you haven't read RM D.8(19) [http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-D-8.html#p19].  The epoch of Ada.Real_Time is unspecified.

Comment: Yes, I've seen it but it worked, at least, on my Linux box :)
So, it gives a possible way of investigation to MartinB

Answer (score 2):

There’s no conversion between `Real_Time.Time` and `Calendar.Time` because `Real_Time` is monotonically increasing (until it overflows, of course; you should be able to expect at least 50 years’ worth, [ARM D.8(30)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-D-8.html#p30)) while `Calendar` may be affected by daylight savings, NTP updates etc.

Would `Ada.Real_Time.Delays.To_Duration` help? (this is a non-standard GNAT package).

I tried

```ada
function To_Duration (T : Ada.Real_Time.Time) return Duration is
   use type Ada.Real_Time.Time;
begin
   return Ada.Real_Time.To_Duration (T - Ada.Real_Time.Time_First);
end To_Duration;
```

but it failed (Mac OS X, desktop; might well work better over an RTOS) with

> `raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : a-reatim.adb:94 overflow check failed`

Failing that, you could use `Unchecked_Conversion` to some unsigned type of the same size as `Real_Time.Time`.

Comment: You can also use _function "-" (Left : Time; Right : Time)_ to get a Time_Span object on which you can apply the _To_Duration (TS : Time_Span)_.
Then using the formatting package for Ada.Calendar and the operator on Calendar.Time, you can rebuild and display the time as expected.